# Join one table with the latest version of the next table

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you suggest a performance efficient version of the below mentioned query by replacing the sub-query.

```
SELECT G.POSTINGDATE,G.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID,I.ID,
I.INVENTORYID,I.VERSIONID FROM ABC G
INNER JOIN XYZ i
ON G.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID=I.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID AND
((G.POSTINGDATE BETWEEN I.POSTINGDATE AND I.POSTINGENDDATE)
OR (G.POSTINGDATE > I.POSTINGDATE AND I.ID = ( 
    select MAX(ii.ID) from XYZ ii
      where ii.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID= i.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID  
      group by ii.clientinstrumentid )))
WHERE G.INVENTORYPOSITIONID IS NULL OR G.INVENTORYID IS NULL
GROUP BY G.POSTINGDATE,G.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID,I.ID,I.INVENTORYID,
I.VERSIONID;
```

This sub-query picks up the latest version for the mentioned clientinstrumentid

```
I.ID = ( select MAX(ii.ID) from XYZ ii 
           where ii.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID = i.CLIENTINSTRUMENTID 
           group by ii.clientinstrumentid )
```

Comment: That's a "correlated" query and correlated queries are known to be slow specially if you run them for many rows. Alternatively you could use a CTE that is not correlated.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a CTE that preprocesses the subquery to pre-compute the `max(id)`.

Even though the correlated subquery is not present anymore, its performance improvement remains to be seen. You'll need to try it out and see if it's faster:

```
with xyz2 (clientinstrumentid, max_id, id, inventoryid, versionid, 
           postingdate, postingenddate) as (
  select ii.clientinstrumentid. ii.max_id, i.id, i.inventoryid, i.versionid,
         i.postingdate, i.postingenddate
    from xyz i
    join (
    select clientinstrumentid, max(id) as max_id
      from xyz 
      group by clientinstrumentid 
    ) ii on ii.clientinstrumentid = i.clientinstrumentid
)
select g.postingdate, g.clientinstrumentid, i.id, i.inventoryid, i.versionid
  from abc g
  join xyz2 i on g.clientinstrumentid = i.clientinstrumentid 
   and ( (g.postingdate between i.postingdate and i.postingenddate)
      or (g.postingdate > i.postingdate and i.id = i.max_id)
   )
  where g.inventorypositionid is null
     or g.inventoryid is null
  group by g.postingdate, g.clientinstrumentid,
        i.id, i.inventoryid, i.versionid
```